# MissingEndpointException: The attempt to connect to the report server failed.

Tags: sql-server-2008

i get this error when i try connecting generating report 
MissingEndpointException: The attempt to connect to the report server failed.  Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, make sure your Reporting service is working.  Try restarting the service.

Comment: I know this might sound stupid but it actually worked, in log file i was having an error of version mismatch. i did everything i could but no results until i stopped and started the server again.

Answer (score 0):

Scan the logfiles in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\Reporting Services\LogFiles and find the following exception: Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2008.RSConnection+MissingEndpointException: The attempt to connect to the report server failed.  Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 404:.

It might be possible that you have configured the /reportserver/ app to not be reachable via http://localhost/... Try following the below things:

1) add the localhost hostheader to the web-site which hosts the /reportserver/ and make sure the app is then reachable via that path

2) edit the file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\Reporting Services\ReportManager\RSWebApplication.config and add the full url to the ReportServer into the ReportServerUrl tag (no ending / nessesary) AND remove the value from ReportServerVirtualDirectory (otherwise you get nasty, unprecise exceptions). THEN you must recycle the app-pool used by the Report-Manager so that config file is being reload.

Comment: I am going to cite this answer as coming from here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/530ed56d-7c84-4d13-8998-80a8bf142197/

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post was long time ago but I posted the answer here in case there's other people facing the same problem.
What I did to resolve this issue is change the URL from Report Manager URL to Web Service URL.

Click [here](http://dyslexicanaboko.blogspot.com/2012/11/the-attempt-to-connect-to-report-server.html) for more details